# Picture moves when browser zooms

Tags: html, css, image, browser, zooming

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and also new on this forum. I have some trouble with the browser zoom function. I want to stick an image to the bottem of my DIV, just like I show you in this picture.
http://imageshack.us/a/img29/1417/n81h.png

But when I zoom with my browser, the image moves and doesn't line up any more with the DIV's bottom, like here:
http://imageshack.us/a/img14/221/vrqd.png

What can I do about it? I've searched a lot but can't find a clear answer.
Thanks!

```
<head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link href="MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background:#81DAF5">
    <div>
        <div ID="Page1">
            Welcome at my portfolio
            <div ID="Creative">Being creative is being me</div>
            <div><img id="head" src="head2.png"/></div>
        </div>            
        <div ID="Page2">Random Text 2 :)</div>
        <div ID="Page3">Random Text 3 :)</div>
    </div>        
</body>
```

```
}

#Page1{
    font-family:Cartoon;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#D8D0F4;   
    width:80%;
    height:80vh;   
    border-radius:60px;
    margin: 10vh auto 10vh auto;
    border: 10px solid #FFE1E1;
        
}

    
#Page2{
    font-family:Cartoon;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#D8D0F4;
    width:80%;
    height:80vh;
    border-radius:60px;
    margin: 20vh auto 10vh auto;
    border: 10px solid #FFE1E1;
}

#Page3{
    font-family:Cartoon;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#D8D0F4;
    width:80%;
    height:80vh;
    border-radius:60px;
    margin: 20vh auto 0vh auto;
    border: 10px solid #FFE1E1;
}
    
#Creative{
    font-family:cartoon;
    font-size:50px;
}
```

Comment: people hardly use the browser zoom. Why do u want to use it? and you should probably post your codes or make a JSFiddle. It seems to be an easy problem to solve. If you make the parent of the image into `position: relative` and the image into `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` that should help. But not sure without seeing your codes first.

Comment: I've added the code. It works for now with the zoom, but the image is not exactly in the center any more, but more to the right. How can I fix this? Thanks for the quick reply!

EDIT:
I've fixed the last part by myself by adding at the image:
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;  
left:50vh;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning if you want to stick your object somewhere!
If you want to place an object somewhere fixed in your parent `div` using absolute positioning,your parent `div` should have some kind of position by itself(fixed,relative,absolute)(otherwise the absolute positioning will occur from the `body` element!!!)

so,in conclusion,you should use `position:relative` for your `Page1` `div` and then use `position:absolute;bottom:0;` for the `div` that has your image in it!